# How to incorporate a CountIf command

Tags: excel, countif

At present, I am using the below SUMIFS command to work out the value of deposits received within a certain date period...

```
=SUMIFS(G2:G4991,E2:E4991,">="&G$167,E2:E4991,"<="&G$168)
```

I am keen to use a form of count command to workout how many deposits were received within this period but am struggling to work it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `SUMIFS()` function works, just create a `COUNTIFS()` function in a cell next to it.

```
=COUNTIFS(E2:E4991,">="&G$167,E2:E4991,"<="&G$168)
```

Comment: This does not work, says I've entered too many arguments for this function?

Comment: @Jamie-LeeHutson, oops my bad! `SUMIFS()` has an extra field `SUM` range and then you enter the criteria. Could you try now :)